# Drag Controls and Jump with one touch game in Unity C#

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am trying to get touch controls to work for iOS, the result i want is drag left to move left, drag right to move right and tap to jump. At the moment the functions do work but what happens is if i don't want to jump and just want to drag the character will jump first as soon as touch the screen. Is there a way i can get the result i want i have added my code below. I want the first touch to just register for the drag and when the player lifts and then taps or maybe double taps the character will jump. Thanks in advance.

```
//Mobile Touch Drag Controls
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            // Get movement of the finger since last frame
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

            // Move object across X plane
            transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    ////Mobile Touch To Jump
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the button goes down, there is no way to know what the player wants to do. You should jump when the finger goes up instead.

An easy solution is to use a boolean to know if the player has moved before the finger was released. If yes, you don't want to jump

```
public class PlayerController // Or whatever name your class has
{
    private bool _moved;

    private void Update()
    {
        //Mobile Touch Drag Controls
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            // Get movement of the finger since last frame
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

            // Move object across X plane
            transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, 0);
            _moved = true; // Remember that the player moved
        }


        ////Mobile Touch To Jump
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if(!_moved) // Only jump if we didnt move
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.up * jumpForce * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
            _moved = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I assume this code goes in your update function. This will work fine but here is a more elegant solution in case you want to try it:

Your class can implement IDragHandler and IEndDragHandler (among others, look for all possibilities that extend [IEventSystemHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IEventSystemHandler.html))

When you implement these, you can override functions that get called when the user touches the screen, such as `public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)`

With this you don't have to use the Update function anymore

Comment: thank you for your help, i am fairly new to programming so please excuse if I am asking something very simple. When i put your code in my update function i get an error saying _moved does not exist in this context. Does that mean i have to declare at the top? if so, what do i have to right?

Comment: _moved is a **member variable** that you have to add. Member variable are defined in your class (while other variables can be defined in a function). A member variable has a different **scope** thand a function variable. I'll edit my answer to show you how to define the member variable. If this is something you don't know, you can google things such as **member variables**, **variable scope**, **c# class usage**. This is an important concept to begin programming

Comment: Ho, by the way, your guess was correct, member variables are usually declared at the top of the class. The important thing is that they are declared **outside** of any function. Also, don't bother with the last paragraph of my answer (about using `IEventSystemHandler`) if you are new to programming. If you understand the code above, it is great already